# Nodejs iconv-lite convert wrong SHIFT JIS Character

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, iconv, shift-jis

I'm having trouble converting **UTF8** Japanese characters to **SJIS**

Library used for conversion: **iconv-lite**

Code:

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite')
const japanText = 'でんぱ組 出会いの歌26 カミソヤマ　ユニ';
const buffer = iconv.encode(japanText, 'Shift_JIS');
fs.writeFileSync('convertedFile.txt', buffer)
```

Result after conversion:

> 'て?んは?組 出会いの歌26 カミソヤマ　ユニ'

Does anyone have the same problem or have a solution please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.js` file seems to saved in UTF-8 with [NFD (Normalization Form D)](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Text editors on macOS often use this type of encoding.

`iconv-lite` cannot handle NFD, so you have to change `japanText` to NFC. There are two workarounds:

#### A) Save `.js` file with NFC

Check the feature of your text editor. For example, if you use Emacs, you can use `ucs-normalize-NFC-region`. If your text editor doesn't have such a feature, you can use a service to convert NFC/NFD like: https://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=7635

#### B) Canonicalize to NFC in your code

Convert the string with `normalize()` method before passing the text to `iconv-lite` like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const iconv = require('iconv-lite')
const japanText = 'でんぱ組 出会いの歌26 カミソヤマ　ユニ';
const buffer = iconv.encode(japanText.normalize("NFC"), 'Shift_JIS');
fs.writeFileSync('convertedFile.txt', buffer)
```